# One-To-Many Relationships in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, relationships

Good morning, I am having a little trouble with model relationships in Eloquent, I need to link articles and images for those articles with an intermediate table. In the intermediate table I'd like to add the id's of both article and image, and I would like to retrieve all the images belonging to an article, what would be the best way to manage the relationship? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many Laravel is pretty well documented, you wouldn't need to ask this if you read the docs.

Comment: one comany has many divisions how to define relationship for this anyone ? 

company table 
division table  company_id primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `morphMany()` relationship ([Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)) to solve your problem like this:

**UPDATE**: The table structure goes like this:

```
- articles
    - id
    - title
    - content
    - ...

- images
    - id
    - owner_id
    - owner_type (Here there can be - Article, Auction, User, etc)
    - name
    - mime_type
    - ...
```

> **Polymorphic relations** allow a model to belong to more than one
>   other model on a single association. For example, imagine users of
>   your application can "comment" both posts and videos. Using
>   polymorphic relationships, you can use a single comments table for
>   both of these scenarios.

You models will look like this:

```
class Article extends Model
{

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'owner');
    }

}

class Image extends Model
{

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

To save multiple images to an article, you can do like:

```
$article->images()->create([... inputs_arr ...]);
```

and to fetch them, you can do this like:

```
$articleImages = Article::find($id)->images;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, how does it save the data on the tables? where does it make the relationship on the db? I created the DB before making the models, because I was previously working on plain PHP. Thanks :D

Comment: There will be 2 tables for this case. Your table structure would be like as shown in my updated answer above.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a problem if I use that image table related to other models, like say auctions, users, etc?

Comment: In that case you can use `Polymorphic Relationships`, let me update my answer for that...

Comment: One list thing, it's highly recommended to create the tables through migrations' isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if you create `migrations` as it would help other developers to get their databases working by writing a single command (helps to migrate DB into different types of DB like - sql, sqlite, etc)..Else developers can face problems while working with your project as their database varies with your code!

Comment: @SantiagoCapdevila - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use pivot table since it's [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship.

Just use `hasMany()` relation:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

And then use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load all images with article:

```
$article = Article::with('images')->where('id', $articleId)->first();
```

Comment: this answer should be selected as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

In Image model class

```
class Image extends Model
{

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
    }

}
```

Then you can access all the images that belong to Article as follows.

```
$image= Image::first();
```

Then for example when we want to get the name of the image that belongs to Article.

```
$imageName = $image->article->name;
```