# One to Many Relationship in Laravel With Food API

Tags: laravel

I want to create a restaurant REST API. But in the `/new_product` endpoint, i need to create a product with respective model, and i pass ingredients id's to the product as an `Array`. Like this: `[1, 2]`. How can i create a relationship in the model to store ingredients in the `IngredientsAssign` table one per one for this product.

If you have any questions let me know.

Actually this is my new product function

```
 public function new(Request $request) {
    $product = new Product();

    $product->user = $request->user;
    $product->type = $request->type;
    $product->size = $request->size;

    $product->save();
    return $product;
}
```

UPDATED:
Guys, i tried with the post similary of this, but i get this error

`Add [0] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Ingredient].`

```js
  class Product extends Model
  {
      public function ingredients()
      {
          return $this->morphMany('App\Ingredient', 'owner');
      }
  }

class Ingredient extends Model
{
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I send that to the API and i need to fill the "part" of the pizza to be place the ingredient.

`{
    "type": 1,
    "size": 10,
    "ingredients": {
        "one": [1,2],
        "two": [1,2]
    }
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One-To-Many Relationships in laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976917/one-to-many-relationships-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: Yes, i read the post, but i get this error when try to do Polymorphic relationships

Comment: To resolve Mass Assignment error, add the ```$fillable``` property or add the ```protected $guarded = []```

Comment: Ok, i solved this problem, but i have a new issue. The Pivot table haves another one value and that is wich "part" of the pizza to place the ingredient. How can fill this value? I send this array to api 

`
{
 "type": 1,
 "size": 10,
 "ingredients": {
  "one": [1,2],
  "two": [1,2]
 }
}
`

Comment: Please show us (and everyone who sees this question in the future) how you solved it by placing an answer. For this next issue, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I use Polymorphic relationship for solve this problem

[One-To-Many Relationships in laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976917/one-to-many-relationships-in-laravel-eloquent)

In this url i found the answer for my problem